# Define variable based on page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to define a variable based on a page slug in *wordpress*. I realize this should be a simple '`if/if else'` statement, but clearly I'm writing it incorrectly. Basically I want to set the variable `$category` to the same as the page title. I do not want to use `$slug`. So I set up my code like this...

```
if( is_page( 'about' )) {
    $category = about;

} elseif ( 
is_page( 'contact' )) {
$category = contact;

} elseif ( 
is_page( 'services' )) {
$category = services;

endif}
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: There are two errors in your code: `$category => 'contact';` should be `$category = 'contact';`, and I guess `$pagename => 'services';` should be `$category = 'services';` instead.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I was editing my post when I uploaded it by accident. I have corrected it.

Comment: Oh, there's one more error in there: `endif;` should be `}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function allows an array of page titles, IDs, and slugs. You can just see if the current page is in an array of those pages, and if so, set the `$category` value to returned value of [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)

```
if( is_page( array( 'about', 'contact', 'services' ) ) ){
    $category = get_the_title();
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much